# Cortar texto de columna en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una columna de una tabla ubicada en un Linked Server (proveniente de Oracle) que excede el varchar(Max) de una columna en una tabla de SQl Server. Necesito cortar los valores al Max de la columna para poder pasar los datos por un Job de SQL Server. Ésta es la consulta que tengo en el paso del Job:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE SMARTCLOUD.DBO.COMMLOG

INSERT INTO SMARTCLOUD.DBO.COMMLOG

SELECT [COMMLOGID]
      ,[SENDTO]
      ,[SENDFROM]
      ,[SUBJECT]
      ,[CREATEBY]
      ,[CREATEDATE]
      ,[COMMLOGUID]
      ,[MESSAGE]
  FROM [SMARTCLOUD]..[MAXIMO].[COMMLOG]
```

La columna que excede el máximo es `[MESSAGE]`

Comment: ¿Cómo es eso? `varchar(max)` puede aceptar 2 Gb de datos (Ver [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms176089.aspx)). ¿Realmente `[MESSAGE]` contiene más de 2 Gb?  Tal vez sería mejor que incluyas más detalles pertinentes a tu pregunta, como cuál error has recibido, una descripción detallada de la estructura de las tablas en SQL Server y Oracle. A lo mejor estás asumiendo incorrectamente la causa de tu problema.

Comment: Lo que dice @sstan es correcto. Qué versión de sql server estás usando? Porque el campo varchar(max) de SQL Server > 2008 podría guardar todo el texto de la saga *El señor de los anillos* sin problema :)

Comment: Y también dinos la versión de Oracle, por favor.

Comment: Como referencia, acaba de hacer una prueba usando SQL Server 2016 con un linked server apuntando a un server Oracle 12c.  Hice un insert de Oracle a SQL Server, como lo haces tu, usando un `CLOB` del lado de Oracle con 1 Mb de datos, y usando `varchar(max)` del lado de SQL Server.  Y funcionó perfectamente sin tener que cortar el texto. Y toma en cuanta que nunca había hecho esto antes, y me funcionó a la primera. Asi que, antes de suponer que necesitas cortar el texto, te sugiero de agregar más información a la pregunta para identificar la causa de tu problema.

Comment: Tienen razón, haciéndolo así no me generó ningún problema, luego de intentar varias prueba y error me di cuenta que el problema era otra columna y no `[MESSAGE]`. Ahora bien, si hubiese querido cortar el texto de una columna la respuesta que me hubiera servido es la de @Ed García. Así que gracias a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `LEFT` de [MSSQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-string-functions.htm#function_left)

```
TRUNCATE TABLE SMARTCLOUD.DBO.COMMLOG

INSERT INTO SMARTCLOUD.DBO.COMMLOG

SELECT [COMMLOGID]
      ,[SENDTO]
      ,[SENDFROM]
      ,[SUBJECT]
      ,[CREATEBY]
      ,[CREATEDATE]
      ,[COMMLOGUID]
      ,LEFT([MESSAGE],X) as MESSAGE/*donde X es el tamaño de tu campo*/

FROM [SMARTCLOUD]..[MAXIMO].[COMMLOG]
```

Comment: Cómo obtengo el tamaño de mi campo, si el tamaño es varchar(MAX)?

Comment: pudieras anidar la función LEN() http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_len.asp

Comment: El problema que tenía era diferente a lo que pregunté, otra columna era la que me generaba el error. Pero como mi pregunta era por cortar el texto, me parece que este es la respuesta correcta a eso. Gracias.